# What is the metal part on top of this connector?

Tags: connector

I'm wondering what the metal parts on top of these connectors are for:
[image]

Are they just for a spot to "grab" for pick and place, and these metal parts will be removed later?

Attribution for picture: Mill-Max

Comment: I believe that's exactly what they're for -- To allow the pick & place machine to grab them and place them on the PCB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that cap is intended to allow a pick & place machine at the assembly house to pick up the connector and place it on the PCB. Depending on the connector and the manufacturer, they can come in metal, plastic, or film ("sticker") types. Here is an example from GCT (Global Connector Technology):

http://gct.co/pcb-board-to-board/pcb-connector-packaging/

Attribution for picture : GCT

[image]

Comment: Thanks for adding the image @placeholder , that was a great idea

Comment: Link rot can set in, it's fair use under trade mark if you provide attribution.  Good find BTW, you beat me to a good picture!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's exactly what they're for. A vacuum pickup needs a flat surface to grab onto.